# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Medoo\Medoo" not found in Project_Asset_Management+Ticket\includes\loader.php:39

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, ticket-system, medoo

I recently created a project to try out Medoo for the first time but I got the error as shown in the title even I do like guidebook.
Can you help me fix it?
Here is my [project](https://github.com/KuugaYuuto/KuugaYuuto-KuugaYuuto-Project_Asset_Management-Ticket-PHP-MySQL)
I would be very grateful and appreciative if you would fix it for me!

I tried every thing in [guidebook](https://medoo.in/api/new) but it still doesn't work.